# Get data into a jq easy ui combobox using php

Tags: php, jquery, combobox

```
   < input id="cc" class="easyui-combobox" name="dept"
   data-options="valueField:'id',textField:'text',url:'get_data.php'">
```

This is a code used in creating a jquery easyui combobox. Can anyone help me with how to write the php code in **get_data.php**. That means for example lets say there is a table called **DEPT** with two colums **dep_id** and **dep_name**.I want to diplay dep_name in the combobox and *valueField* to be dep_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this all the time, and there is no call to a seperate php file to get the results:

```
    <label for="cc">Name of DDB here</label>
                    <select id="cc" name="cc" style="width: 300px">
                        <option value="">--Select ?--</option>
                        <?php
                        $query = "SELECT dep_id, dep_name FROM YOUR TABLE HERE ORDER BY dep_name";
                        $result = $conn->query($query);
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $row['dep_id'] . '" >' . $row['dep_name'] . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

and all of this goes right where you want your drop down box.

Comment: Jim thank you for the answer but can you check whether in the last echo line is (" ") are missing

Comment: @IsankaLakshan no, that is correct, it just goes around the $row['dep_id'].  That is because it is the value in the opening option tag.  If you were hard coding it, and had a variable, say 1 with the wording of yes it would look like <option value="1">Yes</option>